# Redirect all posts to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website like this :

`domain.com/offer1.html`

`domain.com/offer2.html`

etc.

I need to move those pots (`offer1.html`, `offer2.html`, etc )to a subfolder :

`domain.com/folder/offer1.html`

`domain.com/folder/offer2.html`

How can I redirect all those pots ? I can do it one by one by, but there are more than 1000. So looking for an easy way
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, to redirect all the offer pages in the root folder to this folder try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/offer*.html
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/folder/$1 [L,R]
```

Does this help?

Comment: thank you for your answer, "offer" is just an example, all the posts have different slug, for example : offer1.html or christmas-offer34.html

Comment: So looking at your code, I should use this : ^/*.html

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right, assuming all your pages end in .html. Is it working?